# How can I change the css class of each th tag from “T” to “ST”? And how can I assign 1 more function(PI) to the button of the last table of iframe(A)

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe with the following HTML which is empty when I load a page.

```
<iframe id="A"></iframe>
```

I am loading the iframe(A) with the following code using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById(A).src = 'https://adms.lifemark.ca/Apps/app_quickadd_frame.jsp?appid=102946&oppid='+Current;
```

After loading the iframe(A) it creates 10 iframe within iframe(A).Each new iframe has 1 table and many th tag. 
How can I change the css class of each th tag from “T” to “ST” ? And how can I assign one more function(PI) to the following button within the last table of iframe(A) using Jquery?

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="Submit">
<input type="Button" value="Submit" onclick="sb()" style="width:200px">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use  the .content() function to access the iframe.

Then do a .each() to loop between every iframes and then use .click() to assign the function to the button.

Can't be more precise considering the few infos you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#A").load(function () {
    var frame = $(this).contents();
    frame.find("iframe").contents().find("th.T").removeClass("T").addClass("ST");
    frame.find("table:last td.submit input[type=button]").click(PI);
});
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. Everything is working in Firefox but the PI function is not executing in IE.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors when you look at the JavaScript console in IE?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console but the function is not executing.

Comment: @Asif - Are the class names being changed?  If so, here are some things you can check.  Verify that the selector to the button is good - the table really is the last table, the td has a class of submit, and the button really is an `input[type=button]`.  If that's good, make sure your function reference is good.  Is `PI` indeed a function?  Is it defined in the top window?

Comment: Yes the class name are being changed. I checked all the things which you have asked me to check(Verify that the selector to the button is good - the table really is the last table, the td has a class of submit, and the button really is an input[type=button]. If that's good, make sure your function reference is good. Is PI indeed a function? Is it defined in the top window?) but the function is not executing in IE.

Comment: It's difficult to guess without seeing your actual code.  I'd debug it and set a breakpoint in `PI`.